# I need help in fixing my drop down menu from moving when showing <li>

Tags: html, css

The Problem:

Look at Offers and the `li`:

[image]

After putting `position: absolute`

[image]

[Current vs What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrr7T.jpg)

How to make my drop down menu so that when I hover on "Offers" the text doesn't move to the left? I would also like to decrease the width of the li as it is too big for me.

I have tried changing the display: property and putting spaces before and after the word "Offers" in HTML. The spaces worked but I didnt like it because the Offers will just look like having more space than the other options.

```css
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 9em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
}

.menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 0 20px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
    display: none;  /*So li dont show up unless hover */
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li {
    transition: all .3s ease;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a {
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: none;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    color: orange;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="Offers.html">Offers</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Packages.html">Packages</a></li>
            <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="Promos.html">Promos</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a href="Location.html">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to dropdown menu to not move when the li is shown in the Offers. And I would like to decrease the width of black background of the li

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/eshy5qwL/

Comment: @Cichy your example changes how the menu behaves, so instead of appearing vertically now the menu is horizontal.

Comment: Please edit back the question. The idea is that people could use your question for learning.

Comment: You don't have to remove a question after it has been answered. Just accept the answer which you think best answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the sub menu is taking a place and make its parent `li` wider.

A possible solution is to set the `ul` child `position: absolute` so it will not take a place.

Like this:

```css
.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Live example:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg) 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 9em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 0 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
  display: none;
  /*So li dont show up unless hover */
}

.menu ul li ul li a {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: none;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="Offers.html">Offers</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Packages.html">Packages</a></li>
          <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="Promos.html">Promos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Location.html">Location</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about decreasing the the width of the sub-menu (if I understand correctly)?

Comment: @Morpheus I don't like to override the native width of element because it's not generic (if the parent is wider because the menu item's text is longer). Also, it may cut the content..

Comment: @Adrian the `width` comes from the item's content width + the `a` tag has `padding` so you can can remove the `padding` and it will reduce the `width`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirement. The sub menu contains `Packages` which is wider than `Offers` so how it possible that it will be the same width?

Comment: So reduce the `padding`. And notice that it will be no generic, so if, for example instead of `Packages` there will be item `Packages & Packages` there will be nothing to do with it..

Comment: I updated my answer (the code) so now it looks similar. But again, it's only luck it will not work for any case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the min-content size of the list items in the drop down, which are larger than the size of the parent list items in the top menu.

e.g. 'packages' renders at 120px whereas 'offers' is 98px.

The simplest solution is to set a max-width for all the list items based on the max-content size of the longest word (not very dynamic though).

Otherwise, use `position:absolute` to layout the sub menu as in this example:

https://codepen.io/skippingredpanda/pen/xNrxVg

Comment: well the sure fire way is to set `.menu ul li { width: 125px; } ` you's have to change it if menu items are longer than that. The way in my example is not to worry about the descendant width, just stop it affecting the parent width (using `position:absolute;`)

Answer (score 0):

Is simple, use: 
.menu li { position: relative; } .menu li ul { position: absolute; top: your horizontal nav height; left: 0;}

And also you have a mistake in code, must be like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Link 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">SubLink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SubLink 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SubLink 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SubLink 4</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

ul li {position: relative;}
ul li ul {position: absolute; display: none;}
ul li:hover ul {display: block;}
```